# Xcode 4 line of crash in code

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Xcode 3 would show me the line that caused a crash when debugging.
How do you turn this feature on in Xcode 4 ??
I have added an Exception Breakpoint as suggested here but no joy:

[How to display the exact line of code causing application crash in xcode 4 debugger like in xcode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453859/how-to-display-the-exact-line-of-code-causing-application-crash-in-xcode-4-debugg)

Comment: I gave up on xcode 4.2 beta and installed 4.0.2.
Looks like a but in the beta version as works fine on 4.0.2 .